# How to disable automatic sorting in Editable Datagrid in Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, datagrid, flex4

I have an editable datagrid. If sorting is applied by clicking any header of datagrid, it works fine. But after that, if data values are changed in any row of datagrid, sorting is applied automatically. How to prevent from this behaviour? i.e. sorting should only be applied if user clicks on any header of datagrid and sorting should not be applied when user modifies data in grid.

Answer (score 4):

You have to set `sortableColumns` to *false* and handle the `headerRelease` event, where you do the [sorting manually](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/Sort.html) on the data source.

```
<mx:DataGrid sortableColumns="false" headerRelease="onHeaderRelease(event)" ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, My requirement is to stop automatic sorting after editing any column of datagrid i.e if user modifies any column of editable datagrid, itemEditEnd event fires along with automatic sorting. for example if user changes a value in first row, after this change,modified row may become last row of datagrid by automatic sorting. My question is can we stop this automatic sorting? setting sortableColumns to false will only prevent user to stop sorting by clicking on headers.

Comment: @zolo: As I understand your question, the automatic sorting is not applied until you click the first time onto a header.

Comment: yes I want to stop automatic sorting fired just after itemEditEnd even after clicking on headers.But user can manually sort data by clicking on headers any time.

Answer (score 1):

just call `Object(owner).dataProvider.disableAutoUpdate()` before committing the value in your item editor.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you're asking this issue in Flex 4 but I hope the solution that I found in Flex 3 will help.

I also had the same exact problem but then I realized that something in the data must be triggering the sorting to happen.
And it turned out that I was setting the data to be [Bindable]. This made sense to see sorting happened automatically because the value change dispatch propertyChange event.

If you do need to make the data to be [Bindable], use custom binding:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ascomponents_4.html