# flex datagrid - how to pause or block sorting?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

I'm having an issue with a datagrid control. The fields are all editable but when someone edits a *date* field that is currently the sorted column all manner of havoc occurs.

I can see the `itemEditBegin` and `itemEditEnd` events so I'm wondering if there is some way to lock the resorting event until the editing process is complete.

Currently I just have the sorting turned off for these columns but this isn't making friends and needs to be fixed.

Comment: It can help

[how-to-disable-automatic-sorting-in-editable-datagrid-in-flex-4][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228933/how-to-disable-automatic-sorting-in-editable-datagrid-in-flex-4

Comment: I assume you are using a custom item editor? The default item editor solves it by clearing out the sort field on the dataProvider, then reassigning it after the update.